# solve_ivp discards imaginary part of complex solution

Tags: python, physics

I am computing a solution to the free basis expansion of the dirac equation for electron-positron pairproduction. For this i need to solve a system of equations that looks like this:

[Equation for pairproduction, from Mocken at al.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC2IX.png)

**EDIT: This has been solved by passing y0 as complex type into the solver. As is stated in this issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8453 I would definitely consider this a bug but it seems like it has gone under the rock for at least 4 years**

for this i am using SciPy's solve_ivp integrator in the following way:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import scipy.constants as constants

#Impulse
px, py = 0 , 0
#physics constants
e = constants.e
m = constants.m_e # electronmass
c = constants.c
hbar = constants.hbar
#relativistic energy
E = np.sqrt(m**2 *c**4 + (px**2+py**2) * c**2) # E_p
#adiabatic parameter
xi = 1
#Parameter of the system
w = 0.840 #frequency in 1/m_e
N = 8 # amount of amplitudes in window
T = 2* np.pi/w

#unit system
c = 1
hbar = 1
m = 1
#strength of electric field
E_0 = xi*m*c*w/e
print(E_0)

#vectorpotential
A = lambda t,F: -E_0/w *np.sin(t)*F

def linearFenster2(t):
    conditions = [t <=0, (t/w>=0) and (t/w <= T/2), (t/w >= T/2) and (t/w<=T*(N+1/2)), (t/w>=T*(N+1/2)) and (t/w<=T*(N+1)), t/w>=T*(N+1)]
    funcs = [lambda t: 0, lambda t: 1/np.pi *t, lambda t: 1, lambda t:  1-w/np.pi * (t/w-T*(N+1/2)), lambda t: 0]
    return np.piecewise(t,conditions,funcs)


#Coefficient functions 

nu =  lambda t: -1j/hbar *e*A(w*t,linearFenster2(w*t)) *np.exp(2*1j/hbar * E*t) *(px*py*c**2 /(E*(E+m*c**2)) + 1j*(1- c**2 *py**2/(E*(E+m*c**2))))
kappa = lambda t: 1j*e*A(t,linearFenster2(w*t))* c*py/(E * hbar)

#System to solve
def System(t, y, nu, kappa):
    df = kappa(t) *y[0] + nu(t) * y[1]
    dg = -np.conjugate(nu(t)) * y[0] + np.conjugate(kappa(t))*y[1]
    return np.array([df,dg], dtype=np.cdouble)

def solver(tmin, tmax,teval=None,f0=0,g0=1):
    '''solves the system.
    @tmin: starttime
    @tmax: endtime
    @f0: starting percentage of already present electrons of positive energy usually 0 
    @g0: starting percentage of already present electrons of negative energy, usually 1, therefore full vaccuum
    '''
    
    y0=[f0,g0]
    tspan = np.array([tmin, tmax])
    koeff = np.array([nu,kappa])
    sol = solve_ivp(System,tspan,y0,t_eval= teval,args=koeff)
    return sol

#Plotting of windowfunction
amount = 10**2

t = np.arange(0, T*(N+1), 1/amount)
vlinearFenster2 = np.array([linearFenster2(w*a) for a in t ], dtype = float)

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=[24,8])
ax3.plot(t,E_0/w * vlinearFenster2)
ax3.plot(t,A(w*t,vlinearFenster2))
ax3.plot(t,-E_0 /w * vlinearFenster2)
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
ax3.set_xlabel("t in s")
ax3.grid(which = 'both')
plt.show()

sol = solver(0, 70,teval = t)

ts= sol.t
f=sol.y[0]
fsquared = 2* np.absolute(f)**2
plt.plot(ts,fsquared)
plt.show()
```

The plot for the window function looks like this (and is correct)
[window function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKlWI.png)
however the plot for the solution looks like this:
[Plot of pairproduction probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pAfv.png)
This is not correct based on the papers graphs (and further testing using mathematica instead).

When running the line 'sol = solver(..)' it says:

```
\numpy\core\_asarray.py:102: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

I simply do not know why solve_ivp discard the imaginary part. Its absolutely necessary.

Can someone enlighten me who knows more or sees the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), the `y0` passed to `solve_ivp` must be of type `complex` in order for the integration to be over the complex domain. A robust way of ensuring this is to add the following to your code:

```py
def solver(tmin, tmax,teval=None,f0=0,g0=1):
    '''solves the system.
    @tmin: starttime
    @tmax: endtime
    @f0: starting percentage of already present electrons of positive energy usually 0 
    @g0: starting percentage of already present electrons of negative energy, usually 1, therefore full vaccuum
    '''
    f0 = complex(f0)  # <-- added
    g0 = complex(g0)  # <-- added
    y0=[f0,g0]
    tspan = np.array([tmin, tmax])
    koeff = np.array([nu,kappa])
    sol = solve_ivp(System,tspan,y0,t_eval= teval,args=koeff)
    return sol
```

I tried the above, and it indeed made the warning disappear. However, the result of the integration seems to be the same regardless.

Comment: Yes, but that is probably an issue unrelated to this. Eitherway having to define the initial values to complex is definitely annoying but works out now

Comment: If someone ever comes across this and is wondering why the answer was still wrong. Its basically because the "relativistic energy" part E, was above the new definition of m = 1 which is required for numeric stability, pull it down below the "unit system" part and you are good