what happens if solve_ivp's solution contains a complex values?
I'm attempting to use scipy's solve_ivp in order to perform some numerical analysis on Loewner equations, specifically on the first hitting time between the solution and a certain function. My question is, what happens if part of solve_ivp's solution becomes complex? For example, if I am calculating the solution for -2 / (h(t)-(2sqrt(t)+1)) with h(0)=2, and I know for certainty through complex analysis that the solution contains complex values after time 0.05, how will that output look on the solution? So far the output of my solution after time t when the solution becomes complex still spits out real values. Are these the real parts of the complex values? Similarly, can you tell if the solution provided by solve_ivp contains complex values if you weren't sure if it did? I'm using the RK45 method which supports complex values. I also find that when I am using solve_ivp and that solution contains real and complex curves, solve_ivp will stall if it tries solving for complex curves that don't have real parts.
Here is some sample code, the solution should become complex after about t=0.05:
def dh_dt_1cc(t, h, lambda1):
    return (-2) / (h - (lambda1(t)))

def solve_diffeq_1cc(t, steps, h0, lambda1):
    ss = t / steps
    t_span = [0, t]
    t_eval = np.arange(0, t + ss, ss)
    sol = solve_ivp(dh_dt_1cc, t_span=t_span, y0=[h0], t_eval=t_eval, args=(lambda1,))
    return sol

lambda1 = lambda t: 2 * np.sqrt(t) + 1

t = 5
steps = 1000
dt = t / steps
t_eval = np.arange(0, t + dt, dt)
h0 = 2

sol = solve_diffeq_1cc(t, steps, h0, lambda1)

I tried reading the documentation but I couldn't find anything specific about what happens when a real solution becomes complex.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74602588/solve-ivp-discards-imaginary-part-of-complex-solution, unless y0 (the initial value for y) is complex, the solver will solve the problem in the real domain, and discard the imaginary portion.

@NickODell Thank you for that. I decided to plot the solution by passing the complex y0 of [2+0j], only to discover that there is no imaginary component after time t when the solution should become complex. Do you have any insight on why this might be?

Are you discarding the imaginary component when plotting? Matplotlib does that by default.

@NickODell No, I've printed out the solution itself as well to look at the array-output solution and the imaginary part is always 0.
